# https not working on OpenBSD 5.8 & 5.9 guests running in VMWare Fusion 8 Pro

Tags: networking, openbsd, vmware-fusion

The set up is as per title: freshly installed OpenBSD (I've tested both 5.8 and 5.9) are having networking issues when run inside VMWare Fusion 8 Pro (OS X host).

Downloading http files of any size seems to work OK. Downloading https files initially works fine (and at high speeds) but completely halts very soon into the download, after about half a second of downloading.

For example:

```
# git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo
Cloning into 'cargo'...
remote: Counting objects: 20249, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
Receiving objects:   0% (1/20249)
```

And it gets stuck there no matter how long I leave it. Rarely, it gets a fair bit further, it doesn't always get stuck in the same place:

```
# git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo
Cloning into 'cargo'...
remote: Counting objects: 20249, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
Receiving objects:   7% (1418/20249)
```

Using tcpdump I can see that both machines (OpenBSD guest and OS X host) are sending the same ack over and over at the end, before giving up and going quiet.

I am seeing this issue using two types of NAT configuration, both "Share with my Mac" and a private network with NAT enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the virtual network adaptor from e1000 to vmxnet3 resolves the issue. Edit the vmx file for your VM - for me it was `/Users/zofrex/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Router.vmwarevm/Router.vmx`, and change this line:

```
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"
```

to:

```
ethernet0.virtualDev = "vmxnet3"
```

Change other similar lines if you have multiple network adaptors, and note that you might also need to rename your configuration files as this will rename your adaptors, e.g.:

```
mv /etc/hostname.em0 /etc/hostname.vmx0
```

I have no idea what the problem is with the other adaptor, nor why changing to another one resolves the issue, which leaves this as only half an answer really.

Comment: I've accepted this because it fixes the problem, but if anyone can explain _why_ this is happening I'll accept that answer instead